use ogr2ogr shp to s57 error
I have used ogr2ogr -f "S57" 12345.000 12345.shp -skipfailures --Debug ON, but it fails. The console show:

GDAL: Proxy driver FileGDB not registered due to ogr_FileGDB.dll not
being found GDAL: Proxy driver HANA not registered due to
ogr_HANA.dll not being found GDAL: Proxy driver KEA not registered
due to gdal_KEA.dll not being found Shape: DBF Codepage = LDID/87 for
12345.shp Shape: Treating as encoding 'ISO-8859-1'. GDAL: GDALOpen(12345.shp, this=0000023B02034B40) succeeds as ESRI Shapefile.
GDAL: GDALDriver::Create(S57,12345.000,0,0,0,Unknown,0000000000000000)
S57: Can't find attribute depwat from class iscour:Impact Scour. S57:
Can't find attribute depwat from class smalbo:Small Bottom Object.
S57: Can't find attribute stacon from class smalbo:Small Bottom
Object. ERROR 1: Layer '12345' does not already exist in the output
dataset, and cannot be created by the output driver. GDAL:
GDALClose(12345.shp, this=0000023B02034B40) GDAL: GDALClose(12345.000,
this=0000023B02035F30) GDAL: In GDALDestroy - unloading GDAL shared
library.

It looks like short [depwat、stacon]？ How can I do it?
